# Google Apps Script: How to run all the functions in a .gs file?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing my own test runner for Google Apps Script. I want to put all my tests into one (or more) files. Then I will tell the runner which file(s) have my tests, and it should go through each file and run all the functions in it.

However, in order to do that, I need to:

1. Identify which file(s) contains the tests.
2. Iterate through each identified file and find all the functions.
3. Run those functions.

I've tried the following code to identify functions, but its `this` object seems to refer to my entire GAS code base, so it returns all the functions in my entire code base:

```
function functions() {
  for(var i in this) {
    if((typeof this[i]).toString()=="function" && this[i].toString().indexOf("native")==-1){
      Logger.log(this[i].name);
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: rename your function to start with `test` to identify it

Comment: Take a look at the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api)

Comment: By ```files``` do you mean different ```.gs``` files ? I.e are you trying to identify functions from different ```.gs``` files or are all of them in the same script?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf they're all in the same script file.

Comment: For running all the ```functions``` in a script file you could simply create a function that makes a call to the rest of the functions. For example ```function callFunctions(){function1(); function2(); ... etc }```. Is this what you wanted? If not could you share an example of your script (without any sensitive data) to clarify better your intentions? Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution based on @TheMaster's suggestion. All of my test functions are named with the prefix `test_`.

It uses a `try...finally` block because if any of the tests throw an exception and cancel the test run, I want the `finally` block to report.

```
// Run all tests that begin with "test_" from any file.
function run_tests() {
  Logger.log("------ RUNNING TESTS ------", 1);
  try {
    var successes = 0, failures = 0;

    // 'this' refers to the global GAS environment
    for(var i in this) {
      // Find all functions whose names begin with test_
      if(  
        (typeof this[i]).toString()=="function" && 
        this[i].toString().indexOf("native")==-1 &&
        this[i].name.indexOf("test_")==0
        ) 
        {
          // Run a found test.
          var result = eval(this[i].name + "()"); 
          // Increment the count of successes and failures.
          (result) ? successes++ : failures++; 
          Logger.log(`Ran test ${this[i].name} with result ${result ? 'SUCCESS' : 'FAILURE'}`);
        }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    failures++;
  } finally {

    var testcount = successes + failures;
    Logger.log(`----- Ran ${testcount} tests with ${successes} successes and ${failures} failures. :alarm_clock:`, (failures) ? 0 : 1);

  }
}
```